# Using Alfresco workflow-console for deleting all workflows

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I prepare new Alfresco 4.2 server for testing enviroment by cloning repository and database of product server.
I'm going to delete users content, because capacity of repository and database is large.
Problem is that there are many active and ended workflows associated by the content.
Therefore I'm going to delete all workflows in workflow-console Alfresco (http://myserver:8080/alfresco/faces/jsp/admin/workflow-console.jsp) by running command:

**delete all workflows**

Am I to understand correctly that this command will delete all active and ended workflows from repository and database together?

Comment: yes , It will delete all workflow instance from repository.

Comment: thanks, as I understand it, the workflow (process) instances in Alfresco are only active workflows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual command is `delete all workflows imeanit` this will delete only the active workflows.

Url for Workflow admin console :

> http://host:port/alfresco/s/admin/admin-workflowconsole

Comment: It will kill them, but I am not really sure if it also delete their records from DB, etc., so maybe if you will use some methods to obtain "workflow history", you can be possible to see inconsistent data.

Answer (score 1):

Vikas Is correct , The actual command is **delete all workflows imeanit**.It will delete all active and completed workflows from repository/database.

If you check last argument from above command , it is "**I mean It**"

That represents the severity of it.

Comment: I try to run the command and few minutes later get error: 

**org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceException: Namespace prefix iboxdmswf is not mapped to a namespace URI**

After restarting Alfresco, error repeates.
But If I try delete only one any workflow in console, it's ok.

Comment: Finally, I decided to use these scripts for deleting workflows:
http://alfresco.blog.redpill-linpro.com/2016/05/23/tidying-the-alfresco-workflow-database